# My laptop doesn't let me open coordinates in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Vaio laptop and the <kbd>F3</kbd> buttons doesn't work <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> changes volmune and same with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> there is no <kbd>Fn</kbd> lock button, How do I open the coordinates especially since I get lost all the time. Also, how do I use display markers on a map? I tried using maps and searching on the internet.

Comment: You should ask a second question for you're map problem!

Answer (score 5):

It's not <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>FN</kbd>, it's <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: An important distinction but it might help the OP if you expand a bit/explain why the former doesn't work, so they understand why this is the case.

Comment: how did you make the f3 and fn look like keyboard keys

Comment: Use the code <kbd>KEY HERE</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

An alternative would be to change your controls.

Pause the game, to access the main menu. Then choose "Options", and then "Controls". From here, scroll down until you find the command for the "Debug Window", click on the icon (it should currently be set to <kbd>F3</kbd>, as the default), then choose another button, like <kbd>P</kbd> for example.

This way, you won't have to worry about key combinations.